# AJAX call to messages database if new message fire javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

What I am trying to do is detect whether there has been any new messages added to a conversation in a mysql database. If there is the I want to use JavaScript to scroll to the bottom of the page to the last message.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var prevdata;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'inc/aj_chat.php',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#messages').html(data);
            afterdata = data;
        }           
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
        alert(prevdata);
        if (prevdata != afterdata) {

            // Scroll Down function

        }

        prevdata = afterdata;

        },1);

}, 3000);
});
```

as you can see I have a setInterval loop refreshing every 3000ms and im trying to pass the variables from the previous loop into the next loop to compare them. Firstly is this the best way to achieve this and secondly if it is how can I do this?

Comment: I think the best way is by using websockets...

Comment: I agree with @JeroenBellemans. Websockets are a far better choice for chatsystems. As for your question: I would auto scroll down IF scroll is already at bottom. It can be very annoying if you're trying to search for an older message and the scrollbar pops down everytime a new message appears.

Comment: Ok, so lets say I'm using ajax as a fallback technique what would be the best way to achieve the effect im looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this instead:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'inc/aj_chat.php',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#messages').html(data);
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 50) {
            window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
        }
    }           
});
```

So everytime the scrollbar is 50 pixels or less from the bottom, it'll send the scrollbar to the bottom. If it's not, it'll leave the scrollbar alone. You can adjust the number `50` to any number of pixels you want.

So this will make sure your chatsystem auto-scrolls only if the user isn't searching in previous messages.